# Reading text from SMS, and show it as text view

Tags: android, text, sms

I am trying to create app, that will get the text from SMS, and use it in textview. So something like this, message is recived, i check if it is message I want, then i extract text, save it to string, and then show this string in textview. Any suggestions from where should i start, any examples plese ??

Answer (score 1):

You can start [here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) for handling received SMS.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need :) I do have another question, i don't want to display every message, i just want to display certain messages. So when I get SMS text to string, can I check if first word matches to the word I need, and thet display message ??

Comment: You can compare the SMS string with the word you need, if true display message via Toast or in a textview, if false do nothing. This is a matter of Java, if you compare the whole string or just the first word...etc.

Comment: Can you write a sample of this ?? please.

Comment: This is java, you can ask another question with a #java tag or just search on google, I can't write the whole code here.

Answer (score 0):

First I would listen for SMS incoming, and on incoming SMS show a notification. Then if the user opens your app, update your display using this to get the data you want:

```
Uri allMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = cr.query(allMessage, null, null, null, null);

            //shows one message
            c.moveToNext();
            //uncomment to cycle thru ALL messages... This will take AWHILE
            //while (c.moveToNext()) {
                for(int i = 0; i != c.getColumnCount(); i++){


    String columnName = c.getColumnName(i);
                String columnValue = c.getString(i);

                Log.v(TAG, "Col: " + columnName);
                Log.v(TAG, "Val: " + columnValue);
            }

        //}
```

Play around with it a little. It Should have all of the data you need (distinguish SMSs by timestamp)